# Can a WSGI middleware modify a request body and then pass it along?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wsgi

I'm trying to write a middleware that rewrites POST requests to a different method when it finds a "_method" parameter in the body. Someone on the Internet wrote this piece of code:

```
from werkzeug import Request

class MethodRewriteMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, app, input_name='_method'):
        self.app = app
        self.input_name = input_name

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        request = Request(environ)

        if self.input_name in request.form:
            method = request.form[self.input_name].upper()

            if method in ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE']:
                environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] = method

        return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

As I understand the code, it parses the form, retrieves a possible "_method" parameter and if it's found and whitelisted it will overwrite the current method. It works fine for DELETE requests and it rewrites the method with no problems. However, when I try to send a regular, non-rewritten POST this middleware makes the whole app hang. My best guess is that since I accessed the body in the middleware, the body is no longer available for the application so it hangs forever.  However, this doesn't seem to impact rewritten requests, so the code deepest code path (checking the whitelist) works correctly but the other code path is somehow destroying/blocking the request.

I don't think it's relevant, but I'm mounting this middleware on top of a Flask app.

EDIT: I think trying to access the `request` from a handler in Flask is blocking. Does Flask use mutexes or something like that internally?

I'm not even sure how to debug this.

Comment: try just using `from flask import request` and using flasks request object

Comment: you could verify your assumption by not using werkzeug, instead code the relevant query-string parsing based on the environ yourself. This shouldn't be hard (cgi-module helps), and then you can be sure you didn't touch the body. Or better, use the shallow-parameter to Request. BTW, your question is misleading, because the only answer to that is "yes, of course". You can do in WSGI whatever you want to the passed arguments, and if you still conform to WSGI when passing them down (or completely newfangled ones) - good for you. It's just werkzeug's involvement you care about.

Answer (score 1):

`environ` is a dictionary with a `wsgi.input` key that is a stream object. The manual way to do what you're looking for is to read the data, make any changes and then create a new string to replace the old stream in the `environ` dictionary. The example below (without any error handling or other important things) allows you to work with the request body:

```
def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    body = environ['wsgi.input'].read()
    ... do stuff to body ...
    new_stream = io.ByteIO(modified_body)
    environ['wsgi.input'] = new_stream
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

Comment: That will blow out memory use if the size of the request content is very large. WSGI component libraries that handle this do it more intelligently and will write content to a file if over a certain size and then pass on file like object to that. Much better to use one of the existing libraries that do this already. I know Paste or WebOb has something for it, but Werkzeug may as well.