# Reusing Request Body/Data in werkzeug/flask

Tags: python, flask, middleware, werkzeug

I want to access the request body in a flask middleware but problem is once the stream is read im unsure how to get it back for the rest of the service

in my middleware i want to do something along the lines of

```
data = Request(environ).get_data(as_text=True)
```

problem is now the rest of the application fails to access the same data, even if its cached in the Request object i create, it wont be in Flasks (which isnt generated yet)

Comment: You may find a possible approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45201508/13708022).